# Lines drawn on one another makes it thicker and thicker in HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, line, kineticjs

So I have been working on a project for a while, when drawing in canvas is required. I'm using KineticJS lib for the whole canvas stuff but I think it is not the source of my problem. So one part of the project is that I need to draw lines to connect elements and sometimes these lines are drawn on one another so one covers the other and here comes my problem that it not just simply covers it but it makes thicker and thicker and you can really see the difference.

If anyone met the same problem could you please help me? :) Is it a normal behavior? Can I disable it? Because calculating of the already drawn lines and checking if it was drawn before is not really an option here..

Pic of the lines:

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/2dubeyp.png]

(The two on the top are drawn only once, but the two at the bottom are drawn multiple times.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

So here is the code part where I draw these lines.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: _this.containerId,
    width: _this.options.fitWindow?window.innerWidth:0,
    height: _this.options.fitWindow?window.innerHeight-5-61:0,
    draggable: true,
    dragDistance: 10
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();       
stage.add(layer);

var conns = new Kinetic.Group(),
    points = [0,10,100,10];

conns.add( new Kinetic.Line({
    points: points,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#db9e36',
    listening: false
}) );

conns.add( new Kinetic.Line({
    points: points,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#db9e36',
    listening: false
}) );

layer.add( conns );
stage.draw();
```

Comment: Are these Kinetic.Line's? I ask because what your describing typically occurs in regular html canvas. In regular canvas, new drawing commands should begin with `context.beginPath()` or else all previous drawings will be redrawn (and therefore appear thicker and thicker). If they are Kinetic.Line's then we need your code to help you.

Comment: Yes, of course they are 'Kinetic.Line's, okay I will edit my post and extend it with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same points variable to create 2 lines.

```
// one set of points 
points = [0,10,100,10];
```

This causes your 2 lines to be drawn in the same place.

Therefore, your thicker line is really multiple lines drawn on top of each other.

```
// first line using points variable
conns.add( new Kinetic.Line({
    points: points,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#db9e36',
    listening: false
}) );

// second line using the same points variable
// this causes your 2 identical lines to be drawn--resulting in 1 thicker line
conns.add( new Kinetic.Line({
    points: points,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#db9e36',
    listening: false
}) );
```

Comment: Okay, let me clear this, it is not the full code, I only copied the essential parts. Normally, there is a class called Element which draws(calculates the positions and adds to the layer) these lines and there is a foreach which goes through the array of elements and process them. There is a points array in every Element object and sometimes the value of them are the same(depending on some calculations). I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Your problem is with the your design. If 2 Kinetic.Line's overlap then they will appear thicker because they are drawn twice on the canvas. Perhaps you might compare the `points` arrays for all lines and if 2+ are exactly overlapping you could do `duplicateLine.hide()` so that only 1 unique line is shown.

Comment: well that's what I wrote, it is not really an option. because in the real code it is not simply a line, there are 3-4 line breaks too, I tought it is possible to change the rendering mode maybe :/